# we are sorry to the people

Tags: phrase-usage

Is "(be) sorry to the people" natural in English? Google shows that more natural form is "say sorry to x". For "be sorry to x", I am not sure whether it is sufficiently natural in English.

> To Oxfam supporters, friends and volunteers, we are so sorry for the appalling behaviour that happened in our name. More than anything, **we are sorry to the people** of Haiti and other places where the conduct of Oxfam staff has been so reprehensible.

Source: [Bath Chronicle](https://www.bathchronicle.co.uk/news/oxfam-apology-letters-appear-windows-1239657) (UK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a mix, and perhaps could be better expressed. However "sorry for the people of Haiti" would not work.  That would mean "we are sad concerning those people" and doesn't contain the implication of an apology.

The meaning that they intend is "we apologise to the people of Haiti". The word "sorry" has been used instead of the more formal "apologise" as "apologise" sounds more "official" and so less "heartfelt".  But by using "sorry" they have been left with "We are sorry to the people of Haiti", which is slightly odd, but completely understandable.

The usual expressions are

- be sorry for doing something
- say sorry to someone
- apologise to someone